# How to assign variables to array key values

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I have a code in which the array output the result in correctly but I want to assign variable for each key value getting on output. There are no variable in JSON too . all contains values without description.

```
<?php
    $trainNumbers = array(12550,12445);

    $json      = file_get_contents('advcg.json');
    $trainData = json_decode($json, true);
    foreach ($trainData[0] as $train) {

        $trainNumber = $train[0][0];
        if (in_array($trainNumber, $trainNumbers)) {

            foreach ($train[0] as $dataField) {
                echo "{$dataField}\n";          
            }
            echo "\n";

        }
    }
?>
```

The results comes like

```
16032
JAMMU TAWI - CHENNAI CENT Andaman Exp
2013-04-16
TMC
14.606674
79.997721
TALAMANCHI
34
14.564311
79.994888
NLR
NELLORE
24
1

11078
JAMMU TAWI - PUNE Jhelum Express
2013-04-17
BSL
21.0469912
75.7883817
BHUSAVAL JN
158
21.0222615
75.6729054
JL
JALGAON JN
147
17
```

How can I assign variable (description) to first ,second, third,fourth,.... key values 
The first key value is train number,trainname,lat,long.... like this.So that it can be iterated for every set in the array object

The desired output like description should be beside the values

```
train_no-16032
train_name- JAMMU TAWI - CHENNAI CENT Andaman Exp
dep_date - 2013-04-16
dep_station- TMC
dep_log - 14.606674
dep_lat - 79.997721
arr_station- TALAMANCHI
delay_time- 34
new_lat- 14.564311
new_long- 79.994888
new_station- NLR
new_station_name- NELLORE
time_delay- 24
station_left- 1
```

Any idea on this will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: need to sexample of desired output

Comment: @Dagon I have added the desired output in main question.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the fields are always in the same order, something like this will do the trick:

First, create an array with the list of fields:

```
$fields = array('train_no', 'train_name', 'dep_date' ... );
```

Then when processing each item, reference the relevant field in that array:

```
foreach ($train[0] as $i => $dataField) {
    echo $fields[$i]." - {$dataField}\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks beautiful , It worked !!Thanks alot @Mark Parnell

Please one favor more. As I see that value being iterated and got the resposne as expected. But how can I make $train_no,$train_name,.... and echo those as variable.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - can you give more details/an example?

Comment: Like we did 

foreach ($train[0] as $i => $dataField) {
    echo $fields[$i]." - {$dataField}\n";


Can it be like echo $train_no->'value',$train_name->'value',$dep_date->'value'

Actually I need those variables to be called form other sources too.And need to make train

Comment: You mean putting the data into another variable, like: `${$fields[$i]} = $datafield;`? That will be overwritten with each time through the loop so you'd only end up with the values for the last one. To keep them all you'd need to put them into another array, e.g. `$trains[$trainNumber][$fields[$i]] = $datafield;` - that would give you an array of trains with each being an associative array like `'train-no' => 16032, 'train_name' => 'xxx'` etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mark for your valuable expert advice :)

Answer (score 0):

my idea  would be to make an array of the labels

```
$lab=('train_no','train_name');//etc ...
```

then a counter inside the foreach() loop to assign them